# ICS View.getTop() not working

Tags: android, view, touch-event

On my App in the onTouchEvent() I use

```
int y = (int) event.getY() - myView.getTop();
```

to get the relative to my view touch position.

The problem is that in Ice Cream Sandwich myView.getTop() always returns 0.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29) doesn't report any changes.

My App is working fine with SDK Version < 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getTop() reports the Y location of a View within its parent container. If getTop() returns 0, this means your view is located all the way at the top of its parent. event.getY() *already* returns a position in the view's coordinates system.

Comment: Somehow I suspected that, but then how do I "fix" the touch coordinates relative to my view in ICS?

Comment: I think I found where my basic problem is, I'm Overriding onTouchEvent() in the Activity instead of my view, receiving screen coordinates instead of the view coordinates.

Answer (score -3):

I think you ned to use

```
int y = (int)myView.getTop() -  event.getY()  ;
```

Comment: If the problem is that myView.getTop() returns 0, how can reversing the operators solve the problem?